# IPTables input rule filter by device dosnt work

Tags: iptables

This rule work (the packet is added to the queue):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

However , this rule dosnt work (nothing added to the queue):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m physdev --physdev-in eth1 -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Any idea why in input it dosnt add packets to the queue?

No additional rules.
I ran before

```
iptables -X
iptables -F
```

Comment: Is here another rule above this rule which deals with the packet and is a final target like DROP, ACCEPT or REJECT? Then this rule will never be hit.

Comment: @Alex updated question. no other rules.

Comment: I think that the physdev match is solely for bridges. Try using a simple -i eth1 instead.

Comment: You mention a bridge only in your third example, eth1 is a bridge port in the second example right?

Comment: @Alex can you write it as an answer in order to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment seemed to be correct, here again:

I think the physdev match is only for bridges. Try using a simple `-i eth1` instead.

Glad I could help.